# How to choose pandas Sparse dtype and what are the memory implications?

Tags: python, pandas, precision, sparse-matrix, dtype

I am trying to understand how to set up a sparse pandas matrix to minimize memory usage and retain precision of all values. I did not find the answers in the pandas Sparse [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/sparse.html). Below is an example which illustrates my questions:

1. Why does a `Sparse(int32)` dataframe take as much memory as a `Sparse(float32)` dataframe? Is there any advantage in specifying a `Sparse(int)` dtype if this is the case?
2. How does pandas decide what specific `Sparse(int)` dtype to use, e.g. `int8` or `int32`? Given the example below (please see dataframes `sdf_int32` and `sdf_high_int32`), it appears `Sparse(int32)` is always chosen regardless of whether `Sparse(int8)` might be more memory-efficient, or `Sparse(int32)` might truncate some values.
3. Is the only way to avoid truncation and achieve minimum memory usage to specify `Sparse(intNN)` or `Sparse(floatNN)` dtype for each column?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate binary dense matrix with low density
df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
    df[col] = np.where(np.random.random_sample(100_000_000) > 0.98, 1, 0)
df.name = 'Dense'

# Replace one column by values too high for int32 dtype
df_high = df.copy()
df_high['col1'] = df_high['col1'] * 100_000_000_000

# Convert df to sparse of various dtypes
sdf_float32 = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype('float32', 0))
sdf_float32.name = 'Sparse, float32'
sdf_int8 = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int8', 0))
sdf_int8.name = 'Sparse, int8'
sdf_int32 = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int', 0))
sdf_int32.name = 'Sparse, int32'
sdf_int64 = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int64', 0))
sdf_int64.name = 'Sparse, int64'

# Convert df_high to Sparse(int)
sdf_high_int32 = df_high.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int', 0))
sdf_high_int32.dtypes
sdf_high_int32['col1'].value_counts()
sdf_high_int32.name = 'Sparse, int32 highval'

# Print info for all dataframes
print(f" {df.name} Dataframe; Memory size: {df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2:.1f} MB, {df['col1'].dtype}")
for data in [sdf_float32, sdf_int8, sdf_int32, sdf_high_int32, sdf_int64]:
    print(f" {data.name} Dataframe; Memory size: {data.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024**2:.1f} MB,"
          f"Density {data.sparse.density:.5%}, {data['col1'].dtype}")

"""
Dense Dataframe; Memory size: 1144.4 MB, int32
 Sparse, float32 Dataframe; Memory size: 45.8 MB,Density 1.99980%, Sparse[float32, 0]
 Sparse, int8 Dataframe; Memory size: 28.6 MB,Density 1.99980%, Sparse[int8, 0]
 Sparse, int32 Dataframe; Memory size: 45.8 MB,Density 1.99980%, Sparse[int32, 0]
 Sparse, int32 highval Dataframe; Memory size: 45.8 MB,Density 1.99980%, Sparse[int32, 0]
 Sparse, int64 Dataframe; Memory size: 68.7 MB,Density 1.99980%, Sparse[int64, 0]
"""

# Show truncated values for sdf_high_int32
print(f"Values for sdf_high_int32, col1: \n {sdf_high_int32['col1'].value_counts()}")

"""
Values for sdf_high_int32, col1: 
 col1
0             98001473
1215752192     1998527
Name: count, dtype: int64
"""
```

Comment: so where are the print results?

Comment: As `SparseDtype` docs says, it sets the `dtype` of the non-fill values.  The dtype choices are similar to those for 'dense' Series/DataFrames.  And like those for numpy arrays, except pandas adds some extension dtypes.  And truncation issues are the same.  `int8` is limited to small values,, e.g. -127:127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions in your question, first about sparse matrices.  Here is the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/sparse.html):

> pandas provides data structures for efficiently storing sparse data. These are not necessarily sparse in the typical “mostly 0”. Rather, you can view these objects as being “compressed” where any data matching a specific value (NaN / missing value, though any value can be chosen, including 0) is omitted. The compressed values are not actually stored in the array.

That means that only the value chosen not to be stored (`0` in your case) is not stored.  The other values are stored as the datatype you have chosen. `float32` and `int32` both use 32 bits to represent a value, so they consume the same memory.  The difference is what values they can store at what precision.  The same would hold true for `int64` versus `float64`.

Since you only stored 0s and 1s, in your case, you can pick `int8` as well for storing `df`.

Now, answering your `int` question.  Your platform seems to interpret `int` as `int32`.  On my platform `int` is equivalent to `int64`.  Numpy is responsible for this and here is a bit from the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations):

> numpy.int [...] numpy.int64, or numpy.int32
> ...
> For np.int a direct replacement with np.int_ or int is also good and will not change behavior, but the precision will continue to depend on the computer and operating system. If you want to be more explicit and review the current use, you have the following alternatives: [...]

Because in your case `int32` was chosen, you see the values of `0` (obviously) and `1215752192`.  The latter being `100_000_000_000` stored in an `int32`, i.e., there was an overflow and it being stored as `100_000_000_000 % (2**32)` (run this in python) which gives `1215752192`.

BTW, here are the relevant parts from my python interpreter:

```
>>> df_high['col1'] = df_high['col1'] * 100_000_000_000
>>> sdf_int32 = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int', 0))
>>> sdf_int32.dtypes
col1    Sparse[int64, 0]
col2    Sparse[int64, 0]
col3    Sparse[int64, 0]
dtype: object
>>> sdf_high_int32 = df_high.astype(pd.SparseDtype('int', 0))
>>> sdf_high_int32.dtypes
col1    Sparse[int64, 0]
col2    Sparse[int64, 0]
col3    Sparse[int64, 0]
dtype: object
>>> 100_000_000_000 % (2**32)
1215752192
```

Comment: Oh silly me, of course 32 bits is 32 bits :) Do you agree that the `int` part is "default" (wherever it comes from), and it does not take into account truncation/memory efficiency? Would you also be able to answer the third question -- is there a better way to define Sparse dtypes than to check individually for precision and scale for each column? Thank you.

Comment: Found the int documentation and added it, pandas inherits that from numpy, so your assumption >>that the `int` part is "default" (wherever it comes from)<< is correct.